# Creating a new link_to for a nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use the link_to helper function to create a new order for a particular product. Here is my:

product model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :products, :only => [:show, :new, :create, :index, :update, :destroy] do
    resources :orders, :only => [:create]
  end
```

view for product/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'New Order', new_product_orders_path(@product) %>
```

controller for orders

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @order = Order.new
  end

end
```

relevant rake routes:

```
product_orders POST   /products/:product_id/orders(.:format)                                     orders#create
```

But when I do that I get undefined method `new_product_orders_path'

Whats the correct way to do this in Rails 4?

Comment: Is that your full controller code? Post your rake routes output.

Comment: added rake routes. Thats not the full controller code, what else you do need to see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your routes add `new` action here

```
resources :orders, :only => [:create, :new]
```

Also your controller is missing `new` action, in your `create` action you need to save your record

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_product

  def new
    @order = @product.orders.new
  end

  def create
    @order = @product.orders.new(params[:order])
    @order.save
  end

  private

    def set_product
      @product = Product.where("id =?", params[:product_id]).first
    end

end
```

Comment: I did that but I'm still getting undefined method `new_product_orders_path' is that the right helper method?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
    resources :products, :only => [:show, :new, :create, :index, :update, :destroy] do
      resources :orders, :only => [:create, :new]
    end
```

You can also check your routes by typing '/rails/info/routes' at the end of your server path.

Comment: I did that, but I'm still getting undefined method `new_product_orders_path' is that the right helper method?

Comment: I'm sorry.  You also have to create a `new` action in your `OrdersController` as noted in the answer above.